# Moving a PDF from a native iOS Swift app into Salesforce?

Tags: pdf, ios, import

Is there a framework, API or service that I can add to my native Xcode project that allows importing a PDF document from a share sheet button in a native iOS app directly into a Salesforce client profile as an attached PDF?

Comment: I came across these links - not sure if they help? https://github.com/mbotos/CaseMemo and https://developer.salesforce.com/forums/?id=906F00000009COFIA2

Answer (score 2):

1) You need to add [Salesforce iOS Mobile SDK](https://github.com/forcedotcom/SalesforceMobileSDK-iOS) to your XCode project as a first step. You can follow [this tutorial](http://quintonwall.github.io/add-mobilesdk-to-project/index.html) to do so.
2) I don't fully understand what you mean by 'directly into a Salesforce client profile as an attached PDF' but if you want to attach it to a certain object record (e.g. Account/ Contact) - that is certainly possible using REST API wrappers provided in the iOS SDK.

PS - I answered the quoted forum thread question put in as a comment but I believe the use case mentioned here